# tensorflow MonitoredTrainingSession checkpoint hook error: No such file or directory

Tags: tensorflow, pyspark

Hi I am running tensorflow distributed training using `MonitoredTrainingSession`. I created the session using the following code:

```
with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(
        master=server.target,
        is_chief=(task_index == 0), config=config,
        checkpoint_dir='./checkpoints',
        save_checkpoint_secs=30,
        save_summaries_secs=None,
        save_summaries_steps=None,
        ) as sess, train_model.graph.as_default():

    ...

    (_, step_loss, step_predict_count, step_summary, step,
                 step_word_count, batch_size) = train_model.train(sess)
```

However I got the following error:

```
NotFoundError: ./checkpoints/model.ckpt-0_temp_f99363cb89e44afba5df594d2ab72666; No such file or directory
 [[Node: save_1/SaveV2_1 = SaveV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](save_1/ShardedFilename_1, save_1/SaveV2_1/tensor_names, save_1/SaveV2_1/shape_and_slices, dynamic_seq2seq/decoder/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/bias_G100, dynamic_seq2seq/decoder/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/kernel_G102, dynamic_seq2seq/decoder/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/basic_lstm_cell/bias_G104, dynamic_seq2seq/decoder/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/basic_lstm_cell/kernel_G106, dynamic_seq2seq/decoder/output_projection/kernel_G108, dynamic_seq2seq/encoder/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/bias_G110, dynamic_seq2seq/encoder/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/kernel_G112, dynamic_seq2seq/encoder/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/basic_lstm_cell/bias_G114, dynamic_seq2seq/encoder/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/basic_lstm_cell/kernel_G116)]]
 [[Node: save_1/Identity_S37 = _HostRecv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=-8143037005221622295, tensor_name="edge_63_save_1/Identity", tensor_type=DT_STRING, _device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Before this error, there was another message that says:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 0 into ./checkpoints/model.ckpt.
2018-06-14 06:03:50,686 INFO (MainThread-4689) Saving checkpoints for 0 into ./checkpoints/model.ckpt.
```

I did not set up my own checkpoint saver hook, I suppose all the checkpoint saving should be managed by `MonitoredTrainingSession`. So I was sure why it's trying to write to different places. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: have you found a solution to this ? @qkhhly